# Filter query from Combo Box (is Null and Is not null)

Tags: ms-access, filter, combobox, ms-query

I have a combo box that I have set with Null and is Not null options, after slecting the query I want the user to define the query filter from the combo box so I can identify the missing Drawings
How do I then apply a user filter to the query associated (EngDrawingQry.
I applied the following formula to the Query Criteria box for one of the fields , but It returns no results.

=[Forms]![EngReportsFrm]![DrawingNullCombo].[Text]

I also tried a few, IIF functions without success, any help please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3gCV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use no property:

```
=[Forms]![EngReportsFrm]![DrawingNullCombo]
```

Comment: no joy on this one Gustav, still wont perform the filter correctly, when I test the query with Is Null in the criteria box, it works perfectly, as soon as I refer to the combo box form =[Forms]![EngReportsFrm]![DrawingNullCombo], the query provides no results.

Comment: Ah, you have a literal "Is Null" in the combo. That won't work, as you will not check for `Is Null` but the string `"Is Null"`.